# How to use z index for stacking divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to design my very first website using CSS and HTML. But I have run into a bit of an issue.
I'm trying to make a simple sidebar with just a profile picture next to the content container. But, the div pushes down the other div instead of going behind it. I've used position relative and z index but nothing seems to work.

This is how the code looks like now.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <img src="./Img/pepe.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="contentbox"></div>
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Welcome To My Site</h1>
        <h2>First CSS Site</h2>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <ul class="meny">
          <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

body {
 background-color: #E0F2E9;
}

#sidebar{

 border: 2px solid brown;
 text-align: right;
 margin-top: 50%;
margin-left: 0%
}

.contentbox{

 border: solid 2px red;
 width: 60vw;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 height: 100vh;
 margin-top: 300px;
}


.Wrapper {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #5B7B7A;
  margin: auto;
  width: 95vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

.meny{
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 32px;
 border: 2px solid purple;
 padding: 10px 10px;
}

ul.meny{
 margin: 15px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;

}

.meny li{
 display: inline;
 padding: 0px 10px;

}

.meny a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
   font-size: 1em;
}

.Wrapper h1, h2 {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.Wrapper h1 {
  padding: 30px;

}

.Wrapper h2 {
  padding: 4px;
```

Comment: There is not a single z-index in your code.

Comment: Yes you must add the code you got the error. No z-index appears in your css code.

Answer (score -1):

z-index values are relative and it depend to you, for instance :  i write z-index: 50 for my div and z-index : 51 for my another element . Element has z-index 51 comes above div has less value of z-index . i hope this is help .